# Batch file runs twice

Tags: file, batch-file

I have been trying to figure out why this code runs twice and I need your help to find out where I am doing wrong.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (inFile) do  (
   echo %%A >> Out.txt
)
endlocal
```

inFile has some data:

```
Process1
Process2
```

When I run the batch file, Out.txt will have:

```
Process1
Process1
Process2
Process2
```

Please note, I have cleared `Out.txt` before running the batch file.

Comment: This must not be all your code. This prints the filename of inFile to out.txt for me. Are you pulling the data from inside the file out or am I just misunderstanding?

Comment: Your are right, I posted partial code, issue was with this code and I removed it, now runs just once. echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0"
:minimized

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `:end` at the end and in your last line of code `goto end`